# I have a maths question suggesting that it is possible to draw a venn diagram where $A \cup C \ne C$ and $A \cup C \ne A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question explains it: the question suggests that it is possible, but since union includes everything in both $A$ and $C$, I don't see how it can then not include itself. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: You should note the difference between $=$ and $\supseteq$.  Consider $A=\{a\}$ and $C=\{c\}$...

Comment: It should be obviously true that $A\cup C\supseteq C$ and that $A\cup C\supseteq A$.  Something *containing another set as a subset* is different than that something *being equal to another set*.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A=\{1\}$ and $C=\{2\}$. Then $A\cup C=\{1,2\}$ is not equal to $A$ or $C$. You get $A\cup C=A$ when $C\subseteq A$.

Comment: I guess I'm just wondering how you could represent this on a venn diagram - that's what is really confusing me? And thanks!

Comment: @Milo.D Draw two circles so that neither circle is totally contained in the other.  For example in the quintessential image of a venn diagram like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#/media/File:%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%98%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC.svg).  Compare this to where a circle *is* inside of the other circle, something like $\odot$

Comment: Oh - Thank you so much - I completely understand now! Thanks!

Comment: I'll accept when I'm allowed to in a few minutes